# Emacs: Auto Complete for C++

Tags: c++, emacs, autocomplete

i found this autocompletion for Emacs: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete, but I can't find what languages it supports.

I want to use it particular for C++-autocompletion. Has anybody experience with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the [User's Guide](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Builtin_Sources) it has built-in support for C/C++ by means of Semantic. There is also one more tool from the auto-complete mode developer called [GCC Sense](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/), which he claims to be most intelligent tool for C/C++ programming and of course it integrates nicely with auto-complete so you might have a look at it as well.

Answer (score 5):

Setup of Emacs with CEDET for autocompletion for C++ is described in [my article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html).  You can look to [my CEDET config](http://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el) for working setup